# Calculating maximum extent of debris flow from point with mean slope value

Tags: qgis, saga, slope

At a very large scale I perform a spatial analysis for which I have to apply mean slope criteria. These criteria allow me to calculate the maximum extent of an event (debris flow). I know that below a certain slope threshold, my debris flow stops. In theory, finding this extent seems simple, but in practice I can't find any GIS tools that allow me to get this.

The data I have are:

- The starting points (raster or vector)
- The average slope value
- The flow paths for each starting point
- The altitude values (MNT)

I expect a spatial extent (raster or vector) as a result.

**Is there a tool to calculate a maximum spatial extent by entering a starting point and an average slope as a parameter?**

I work mainly with QGIS and SAGA so I would prefer solutions for these softwares